# "No such file or directory" when starting convolutional.py script on tensorflow docker image

Tags: python, docker, anaconda, tensorflow

I don't have a Linux or Mac machine so in order to check out TensorFlow on Windows, installed docker and downloaded the image of tensorflow-full.
When I run the following command:

```
$ python tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py
```

I get this error message:

```
C:\Users\Javiar\Anaconda\python.exe: can't open file 'tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Currently on Win 8.1 and have anaconda installed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like the error message is caused by trying to execute a script file (`.../convolutional.py`) that is inside the container, using the Python interpreter outside the container.

First of all, follow the steps here to ensure that Docker is configured successfully on your Windows machine:

http://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/#using-docker-from-windows-command-prompt-cmd-exe

Once you've successfully run the `hello-world` container, run the following command to start the TensorFlow container:

```
docker run -it b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow
```

(Note that, depending on your terminal, the previous step may or may not work. A common error is `cannot enable tty mode on non tty input`. In that case, run the following command to connect to the VM that is hosting the containers:

```
docker-machine ssh default
```

...then at the resulting prompt, the `docker run` command again.)

At the resulting prompt, you should be able to run the script with the following command:

```
python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py
```

Comment: The installation of docker went well as I was able to some example from the docker tutorial site. When I run the command:
`docker run -it b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow` 
I get the following error:
> cannot enable tty mode on non tty input

Comment: It looks like this is a known issue: http://tdeheurles.github.io/How-to-install-docker-on-windows/

One possibility is to do: `docker-machine ssh default` to connect to the VM that hosts the containers, then do `docker run -it b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow` from the resulting prompt.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks @mrry. Based on ur previous comment it now works flawlessly!